# How do I direct a program (eg: browser) to use a specific ethernet connection?

Tags: ethernet

I have 2 Ethernet connections

For Windows

1) Name: Ethernet

For Virtualbox

2) Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network

Can I use other programs other than Virtualbox to use the #2 ethernet connection instead of the #1 without changing what the OS uses to connect to the internet?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you want to solve?

Comment: My understanding is that the VirtualBox Host-Only Network adapter is exactly what it says it is - an adapter for connecting VirtualBox Guests to the Host. It seems unlikely you can co-opt it for some other purpose.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want Windows 10 to be an offline machine so ethernet 1 has ipv4 and ipv6 are disabled. I'd like 1 additional program other than virtualbox to use Ethernet 2. If 2 cannot be shared can I make a single software use using a 3rd ethernet connection specifically for 1 software?

Comment: If Windows 10 is the host, then VirtualBox needs its network connections to talk to the outside world.   You may want to describe the actual setup in more detail because it is very unclear what you want to do, and why?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If it cannot be used can I create a 3rd ethernet connection and allocate it specifically for 1 software?

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this instead of just setting up a proxy?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Been there, done that. I have used proxies before they don't work for Windows, it still find a way to bypass them next thing you know you have a message saying updates are ready to install. No thank you.